# How do I evaluate a quantification expression within a Z3 model evaluation?

Tags: z3, z3py

Consider the following, which creates a simple model where a string is equal to a specific value:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x = String('x')
s.add(x == StringVal('foo'))
s.check()
```

I then want to ask whether there exists a string that is equal to `x`'s model value:

```py
y = String('y')
expr = Exists(y, y == x)
print(s.model().evaluate(expr))
```

I would expect this to return a boolean value, but instead the output is itself an expression:

```
Exists(y, y == "foo")
```

How do I get this expression to be actually evaluated within the `evaluate` method, instead of coughed back up? I'm assuming `evaluate` doesn't like the fact that I introduced a new unbound variable, but surely putting that variable within an `Exists` (or for that matter, a `ForAll`) is sufficient for the expression to be evaluated? Is there a way to write quantification methods without introducing a new unbound variable?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out quantification is slightly beyond what Z3 supports in the `evaluate` method (which makes sense). The workaround is to re-run `s.check()` if `evaluate` returns a `QuantifierRef`:

```py
result = s.model().evaluate(expr)
print(result)
if isinstance(result, QuantifierRef):
  s.push()
  s.add(result)
  print(s.check())
  s.pop()
```

Of course, you can also ask why you're even bothering with an `evaluate` call instead of just putting `expr` as an additional constraint before the call to `check`.

Comment: A top-level `exists` is the same as a declaration of a variable. So, it's not clear to me what your `Exists(y, y == 'foo')` is achieving at all. Why not just use `x` to query the result? Perhaps you're trying to do something else entirely, but as stated this question doesn't seem like something you'd actually want to do.

Comment: @alias this is of course a boiled-down example but basically I had some quantifications deep in an expression tree that I was trying to evaluate. Anyway I just decided to move the expression tree as a constraint before solver.check(), which took a bit to wrap my head around conceptually but seems to work.

Comment: If you have nested quantifiers, there's no easy way to access them in a model. You just have to "arrange" for them to be at the top-level. If they are existential, then the traditional way to do this is to use skolem functions.